# Apache redirect rule for ServerAlias domain name redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, vhosts

I have two different domain names in one `vhost`

```
<VirtualHost *:7080>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.ex2.com
DocumentRoot /web/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to add a rewrite rule for www.ex2.com without affecting www.example.com:

```
RewriteRule "^/home.html$" "/index.html" [R=301,L]
```

it is to redirect www.ex2.com/home.html to www.ex2.com/index.html

How can I write a rewrite rule that only applies to ServerAlias `www.ex2.com` and does not affect `www.example.com/home.html` page?

Answer (score 0):

Precede the new rule with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.ex3.com` to restrict it to your serveralias.

Comment: will you please explain this in detail